# how to set timer properly in wxpython

Tags: python, list, timer, save, store

**My problem is**: how to use Timer properly? Sometimes i missed the data.
part of the code:

```
import wx
import serial 

store=[]
class all(wx.panel):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        …
        self.SetSizer( bSizer17 )
        self.Layout()

        self.timer1 = wx.Timer()
        self.timer1.SetOwner( self, 1 )
    
        self.timer2 = wx.Timer()
        self.timer2.SetOwner( self, 2 )
        self.timer2.Start( 500 )         ### running when app begins
    
        self.timer3 = wx.Timer()
        self.timer3.SetOwner( self, 3 )
        self.timer3.Start( 401)          ### running when app begins 

    def timer1(self,event):
        if self.timer1.IsRunning():
            self.timer1.Stop()
        else:
            self.timer1.Start( 100 ) 
    def timer2(self, event):
        event.Skip()
    def timer3(self, event):
        event.Skip()

    def timer1_plot(self, event)
         …
        plt.plot(x,y)
    def timer2_store( self, event ):   
        for line in ser:
            store.append(line)
        with open("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\saved_data.txt","a") as f: 
            for line in store:            
                f.writelines(str(line)+ "\n")
    def timer3_del( self, event ):           
        del store[:]
```

I have coming data from serial port per second. I use data for plotting and saving background(independent from plotting). For this i used wxTimer.

I have 3 buttons(bind with timers), 2 of them are hidden(2 timers run automatically).

1.button is for **plotting**. When i press, timer run.

2.button is for **storing and writing to .txt file and delete from the list**

3.button is for **deleting the stored data in the list**

> self.timer1.Start( 100 )       # running when button press
>
> self.timer2.Start( 500 )       # running when app begins
>
> self.timer3.Start( 401)        # running when app begins

range between timer is good? Should i run 2 of them automatically? What can you suggest? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty old, so you may have already found a solution... but here is my advice.
My project monitors 2 serial ports, one has a scale that sends a data packet every second, the other has a barcode scanner - very random when data arrives.

I use 1 thread per serial port, that just timer.sleep's waiting for serial input, and stores it in a shared object (1 object per thread).  Then I have one timer that updates the state machine, it looks at each shared object, and updates the GUI accordingly.

If this was my project, I would suggest the following changes:

- Don't call timer event .Skip() nothing else should be chained after your callback.
- Create a thread for each serial port or other async communication source.
- Be sure to mark the threads as daemon's or explicitly kill them when shutting down.
- Use one timer that updates everything, use the lowest frequency that gives your users acceptable response.

Good luck.